# How to extract a valid number from string even if it is followed by zeroes

Tags: shell, awk, sed

A question for `sed` and `awk` experts.

If I have a string like this : `ABCDEF00012300XYZ`. 
I want to extract the number that follows the alphabets and the zeroes. So, I want to extract `12300` from the string.

By spirit, I just want extract the valid number in the string. `00012300` means `12300` in mathematical sense.

I tried the following

```
STR=ABCDEF00012300XYZ
VALID_NUMBER="$(echo $STR | awk '{sub(/.*0+/,"");sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"")} 1')"
```

Above works if I pass `ABCDEF000123XYZ` and it extracts `123` from `STR`. But fails if `123` is followed by zeroes in which case it should get `12300`.

Note that this is `sed` on linux that I am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `sed`:

```
VALID_NUMBER="$(sed 's/^[A-Z0]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' <<< "$STR")"
```

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/fB2Qlm).

The `^[A-Z0]*\([0-9]*\).*` pattern will match:

- `^` - start of a line
- `[A-Z0]*` - any uppercase letters or zeros, 0 or more repetitions
- `\([0-9]*\)` - this will capture 0 or more digits into Group 1
- `.*` - this will match the rest of the line.

Then, the `\1` in the replacement pattern will only keep the number you need in the output.

Comment: Perfect. Works! Thanks for the explanation about the character match

Answer (score 2):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '
match($0,/[1-9][0-9]*/) {            # match first non-zero leading string of numbers
    print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)  # and print it
}' <<< ABCDEF00012300XYZ             # or you could echo ... | awk ...
12300
```

Or sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^[^1-9]*|[^0-9]+$)//g' <<< ABCDEF00012300XYZ
12300
```

That sed script replaces from the beginning all `[^1-9]` and from the end `[^0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(tested with GNU `awk`).

```
echo "ABCDEF00012300XYZ" |
awk '
  match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+0+[0-9]+/){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+[^1-9]0+/,"",val)
    print val
   val=""
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
echo "ABCDEF00012300XYZ" |               ##Printing value by shell echo command here and sending its output as standard input for awk command.
awk '                                    ##Starting awk command here.
  match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+0+[0-9]+/){         ##Using match for matching regex for continous alphabets with continous zeros and then following digits in match OOTB function of awk.
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)        ##Creating variable val whose value is sub string of current line whose starting point is RSTART till value of RLENGTH.
    gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+[^1-9]0+/,"",val)     ##Using gsub to globally substituting alphabets then continous zeroes Leaving other digits(till other digit occurence comes) for val here.
    print val                            ##Printing val value here.
   val=""                                ##Nullifying variable val here.
}'                                       ##Closing BLOCK for awk program here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another GNU awk solution:

```
$ STR=ABCDEF00012300XYZ                                                          

$ awk -v str="$STR" 'BEGIN{print gensub(/[A-Za-z0]+([0-9]+).*/, "\\1", 1, str)}' 
12300
```

However, if it's not limited to *after alphabets and zeros*, then it's better like this:

```
awk -v str="$STR" 'BEGIN{print gensub(/[^1-9]*([0-9]+).*/, "\\1", 1, str)}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With Parameter Expansion :

```
str="ABCDEF00012300XYZ"
inter="${str%${str#*[[:digit:]]}}"
str="${str#${inter%[[:digit:]]}}"
inter="${str%${str#*[![:digit:]]}}"
str="${str%${str#${inter%[![:digit:]]}}}"
inter="${str%${str#*[1-9]}}"
str="${str#${inter%[1-9]}}"
echo "valid_number = $str"
```